# MOODLE MySQL using 'and' in SELECT part of statement

Tags: mysql, moodle

In MOODLE, I'm using the following script to pull some numbers -- and they come out fine:

```
SELECT
qc.name,
q.category,
SUM(IF(qs.grade = "1",1,0)) AS Correct,
SUM(IF(qs.grade = "0",1,0)) AS Wrong

FROM
mdl_question_states qs,
mdl_quiz_attempts qa,
mdl_quiz qz,
mdl_course c,
mdl_question q,
mdl_question_categories qc

WHERE
qa.id = qs.attempt
AND qs.event = 6
AND qa.quiz = qz.id
AND ((qz.name = 'Pre-Test') OR (qz.name = 'Post-Test'))
AND qz.course = c.id
AND q.id = qs.question
AND q.category = qc.id
AND q.category > 601

GROUP BY q.category

ORDER BY qc.name
```

My question is this: I want to have a column (after the 'SUM(IF...' columns) that are 'Correct -AND- Pre-Test' followed by 'Correct -AND- Post-Test'.

What is the syntax to use to accomplish this?

Comment: I take it you get that pre-/post-test stuff from qz.name?

Comment: `sum(if(qs.grade='1' and qz.name='pre-test'), 1, 0)) as cor_and_pre`

Comment: I'm getting error 1064 (42000) when I execute the statement. Here's my updated SELECT statement:
    `SELECT

    qc.name,

    q.category,

    SUM(IF(qs.grade = "1",1,0)) AS Correct,
    SUM(IF(qs.grade = "0",1,0)) AS Wrong,
    SUM(IF(qs.grade = "1" AND qz.name='Pre-Test'),1,0) AS PreCorrect,
    SUM(IF(qs.grade = "0" AND qz.name='Pre-Test'),1,0) AS PreWrong,
    SUM(IF(qs.grade = "1" AND qz.name='Post-Test'),1,0) AS PostCorrect,
    SUM(IF(qs.grade = "0" AND qz.name='Post-Test'),1,0) AS PostWrong`

Comment: should be `,1,0))`, not `),1,0)`. you're putting the if's true/false parameters into the sum() function. looks like I had the same typo in my example above.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. I was sure that I had tried every combination of parentheses, but... Thank you @MarcB
p.s. - You might want to make your suggestion an 'Answer' so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SUM(IF(sq.grade = '1' AND qz.name='pre-test', 1, 0)) AS cor_and_pre
```

and similarly for the other value.